# How do I use @NotEmpty constraint to validate an HTTP request body in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, validation, spring-mvc

I have a RestController containing an HTTP endpoint to create a new user.

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
  @PostMapping("/user")
  public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<UserResponse>> createUser(
      @Valid @RequestBody UserRequest userRequest) {

    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(
        ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED).body(userService.createUser(userRequest)));
  }
}
```

My UserRequest model is as follows:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserRequest {

  // @NotNull
  @NotEmpty private String name;
}
```

Now, every time I invoke the POST /user endpoint with a valid payload (e.g., `{ "name": "John" }`), I get the following error:

```
HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty' validating type 'java.lang.String'. Check configuration for 'name'"
```

In other words, the exception is thrown regardless of whether the "name" property was empty or not.

However, when I use the `@NotNull` constraint instead, the exception is only thrown in the absence of the name property or `{ "name": null }`, as expected.

Am I misusing the @NotEmpty constraint?

Comment: Please refer: https://www.baeldung.com/java-bean-validation-not-null-empty-blank

Comment: Judging from the error message the problem is not with your usage of the annotation it is a run-type dependency issue. Have you got another version of the hibernate validator library on the classpath?

Comment: @jtsnr As a matter of fact, I do have hibernate-validator v6.0.16.Final defined on the classpath. Would that affect the behavior in any way?

Comment: I found this link is helpful for the same problem https://blog.tericcabrel.com/validate-request-body-and-parameter-in-spring-boot/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven dependencies  (in pom.xml) -

```
<!-- Java bean validation API - Spec -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
 
<!-- Hibernate validator - Bean validation API Implementation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
 
<!-- Verify validation annotations usage at compile time -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

In the user request model-

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty; 

@NotEmpty(message = "Name cannot be empty")
    private String name;
```

Comment: The [Hibernate Validator Annotation Processor](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-annotation-processor) appears to be a useful build time check. I'll add that to the annotationProcessorPaths option. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For validation String's variable, you should use `@NotBlank` this constraint check null and blank value for String's variable(blank for example "" or " ") or `@NotNull` if you want to check the only nullable value

`@NotEmpty` for Collection's type check.

Check this for more information: https://www.baeldung.com/java-bean-validation-not-null-empty-blank

Comment: The @NotEmpty example uses a String in the baeldung link you provided which demonstrates that the validation works!